# Google Tag Manager not able to fetch all the values from default container file when running app for first time with no network available

Tags: android, offline, google-tag-manager

I have integrated Google Tag Manager in my app and downloaded the latest version binary file and stored in res->raw folder. My GTM container consists of almost 150 key value pairs. The issue is that when I run the app for first time with no network  available, app is not able to fetch all the values from default container file.I see many missing or blank values when I run the app.However if I connect to internet and then load the container and then reopen app with no network available than it is able to fetch all the values from default container file. Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

```
   TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(this);
    PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending =
            tagManager.loadContainerPreferNonDefault(CONTAINER_ID,
                    R.raw.gtmxyz);
    pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull ContainerHolder containerHolder) {

            ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
            ContainerHolderSingleton.getContainerHolder().refresh();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


                @Override
                public void run() {

                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,XYZ.class));

                    finish();
                }
            }, AppConstant.SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things you can do to ensure that this works:

1. Make sure the default container (the one in R.raw.gtmxyz) is the most recent version of your container. You can download the latest version from the versions tab in Tag Manager:
   [image: Versions action drop down]
2. In your onResult callback, you should call getContainer on the container holder. This makes the newly loaded container the current one.
3. You don't need to call refresh on the newly loaded container.
4. Ensure that code or UI elements using your container's values doesn't get invoked before the container has loaded.